# Mute Outlook app on iPhone during holidays

Tags: iphone, office-365

I have an iPhone which I use for work and private. Now I'm on holidays for a week and I don't want to see any notifications or e-mails.

Is it possible to mute (or completely turn off) the iPhone Outlook app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to receive notifications for the week you can simply disable notifications in the notification center.

Steps

1. Go to Settings (the settings app for the iPhone)
2. Tap on Notification Center
3. Find Outlook and Tap on it
4. Tap the slider next to Allow Notifications to turn it off.

This will turn them off so you do not receive any notifications. To turn them back on follow these steps.

1. Go to Settings (the settings app for the iPhone)
2. Tap on Notification Center
3. Find Outlook and Tap on it (This time it will be under the do not include section)
4. Tap on the slider next to Allow Notifications to turn it on.

Comment: Haha, awesome! It can be so easy! Thanks for answering my noob question.